Can we paste into google sheet(spreadsheet) bulk data from Clipboard(windows) at once?
I am working on google sheet, sometime it takes time to copy and paste into google sheet(spreadsheet).
I am looking for a shortcut so that when I copy some data from somewhere, it gets saved on the clipboard in windows. Once I finish copying can I paste all the data from theclipboard history to a Google Sheet at once? If I do so, does it get generalized to a respected cell. Is there any formula or script to do it? Any help appreciate it.
I tried searching online, but could not find any.
